# asp login save cookies for user account

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I wonder how I can use the cookie for asp login when the whole login seems to be wrapped as a control (I can't see textbox user and textbox password inside the asp code).

the code for login is

```
       <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#EFF3FB" BorderColor="#B5C7DE" BorderPadding="2" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333" Height="186px" Width="438px" RememberMeSet="True" EnableViewState="true">
    <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
    <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#507CD1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284E98" />
    <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#1B4D82" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />
</asp:Login>
```

the code behind my login page is:

```
          Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
           If Not IsPostBack Then

          '------------------------------get cookies-----------------------
        If ((Not (Request.Cookies("UserName")) Is Nothing) _
                    AndAlso (Not (Request.Cookies("Password")) Is Nothing)) Then
            Login1.UserName = Request.Cookies("UserName").Value
            'Login1.Password.value = Request.Cookies("Password").Value  '----how Can I write this row correctly??
        End If
    End If

     '--------------------check authentication-------------
Dim username As String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

   If Not username = Nothing And User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = True Then

        Server.Transfer("Home1.aspx")


  End If


 End Sub
```

The authentication is my web.config is

```
         <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" loginUrl="abc/def/login.aspx" defaultUrl="abc/def/login.aspx" timeout="60" cookieless="UseCookies"/>   
          </authentication>
```

the code after loggin in is

```
    Protected Sub OnLoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Login1.RememberMeSet = True Then
        Response.Cookies("UserName").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
        Response.Cookies("Password").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)
    Else
        Response.Cookies("UserName").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        Response.Cookies("Password").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    End If
    Response.Cookies("UserName").Value = Login1.UserName.Trim
    Response.Cookies("Password").Value = Login1.Password.Trim
End Sub
```

After I log out, the cookies don't get saved (even though I checked remember me). I wonder how to fix the issue? Typically, I'm not sure how to retain the password in the login window after log off.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

> `I'm not sure how to retain the password in the login window after log off`

Generally, only username should be kept in the login form after logged-out, right?. If you logout the cookie and session will be destroyed, won't they? What is your Logout button event code?

Sometimes if you are using a shared hosting server, the session only lives in a very short amount of time (10-20 mins) if it is expired the cookie will be also gone.

Comment: yes, but the user wants less security and he simply wants to see password filled even after logging out, then he can simply click log-in to log in again